# How to simplify the following code using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

```html
<div class="col autocomplete theme-standard pin-left" data-control="autocomplete" data-auto-pos="true">

    <label class="text autocomplete-arrow icon-before" id="FH-origin-label">
        <span class="label">Leaving from</span>

        <span class="visuallyhidden">City or airport</span>

        <input type="text" name="FrAirport" data-canonic="origin" id="FH-origin" data-minchar="3" data-provide="autocomplete" data-template="#uitk-autocomplete-default" data-theme="autocomplete" data-closetext="Close" data-continuetext="Continue typing to refine search" data-lob="PACKAGES" data-mask="95" data-version="v4" data-locale="en_US" data-forceicon="flights" data-autoselect="touch" data-selectioncallback="publishingWizardPackageTypeAheadOriginCallback" placeholder="City or airport" xpath="1">
        <span class="icon icon-location" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </label>

    <div class="autocomplete-dropdown"></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to select one of the 'Leaving from' section on the following website using chrome webdriver using while loop: https://alaskatrips.poweredbygps.com/g/pt/hotels?MDPCID=ALASKA-US.TPS.BRAND.hotels.HOTEL

I have tried the code below:

```java
    package dropdowns;

    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

    public class synchronization {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
        "C:\\Users\\everybody\\Desktop\\selenium\\library\\chromedriver.exe");
       WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
       driver.get("https://alaskatrips.poweredbygps.com/g/pt/hotels?MDPCID=ALASKA-US.TPS.BRAND.hotels.HOTEL");
       driver.manage().window().maximize();
       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

       WebElement a = driver.findElement(By.id("FH-origin"));

       a.sendKeys("NEW");
       while (!a.equals("New Haven, CT (HVN-All Airports)")) {
        //Thread.sleep(4000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("FH-origin")).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);

        driver.findElement(By.id("FH-origin")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
       }
```

Comment: Edit your question and post the relevant error message and make sure you indicate which line of code the error appears.

Comment: From your post, it seems the exception is thrown at line 31. Could you please update the code up to that point and post the error stack trace.

Comment: When I paste your shown code in NotePad++ there's only 29 lines, so I don't know what line 31 is unless your error message states that perhaps it's in a different class?  My hunch is that you are not declaring or passing ChromeOptions in your browser instantiation, but it's hard to confirm without knowing exactly where your reported error is.  Please provide more details, as others have repeatedly requested.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
while (!a.getText().equals("New Haven, CT (HVN-All Airports)")) {
            Thread.sleep(4000); //what is the need of this Thread sleep?
            driver.findElement(By.id("FH-origin")).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN); 
        }
driver.findElement(By.id("FH-origin")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

i just fixed your code based on my assumptions

posting the HTML would help other SO users find the answer for your question

Comment: Please take some time to read the question. OP mentioned _...But i keep seeing the **chrome not reachable** err..._

Answer (score 0):

### Code simplification:

In the given page,
after entering a few letters it loads the autocomplete suggestions in a list.

You have to wait for the autocomplete drop down to show up. To do that use explicit wait because it waits until the element is visible and not more.

**Explicit Wait:**

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(autocomplete));
```

After that, you have to find the item that contains 'New Heaven' and click on it. You can use XPath to find elements containing specific text.

**XPath:**

```
//*[@id='backwards']/li/a[contains(.,'New Haven')]
```

Now that you already found the item, you don't have to run a loop to find the element anymore.

TRY This:

```
driver.get("https://alaskatrips.poweredbygps.com/g/pt/hotels?MDPCID=ALASKA-US.TPS.BRAND.hotels.HOTEL");

WebElement leavingFrom = driver.findElement(By.id("FH-origin"));
WebElement autocomplete = driver.findElement(By.className("autocomplete-dropdown"));

leavingFrom.sendKeys("NEW");
//after entering sample text wait for the autocomplete drop-down to show up 
new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(autocomplete));
WebElement newHaevn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='backwards']/li/a[contains(.,'New Haven')]"));
newHaevn.click();
```

For this, you have to import

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
```

---

### Possible Error Fix:

For the `Chrome not reachable` exception possible solutions are:

- Update the [selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)
- Update the Chrome to latest version
- Update the [chromedriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) for the specific chrome version
- Use the `no-sandbox` chrome option.

```java
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

  -